# Need Help in taking Input from DataInputStream in java

Tags: java, datainputstream

Here's my code :

```
import java.io.*;

class InterestCalcs {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Float prinAmount = new Float(0);
        Float ROI = new Float(0);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        String tempString;
        int noOfYears;
        System.out.println("Enter Amount :");
        System.out.flush();
        tempString = in .readLine();
        prinAmount = Float.valueOf(tempString);
        System.out.println("Enter ROI:");
        System.out.flush();
        tempString = in .readLine();
        ROI = Float.valueOf(tempString);
        System.out.flush();
        tempString = in .readLine();
        noOfYears = Integer.parseInt(tempString);
        float interestTotal = ROIprinAmountnoOfYears;
        System.out.println("The total interest is " + interestTotal);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i am getting "InterestCalc.java uses or overrides a deprecated API." during compilation

Comment: I am a novice programmer I really dont understand what does "stack trace" mean?

Comment: Post the full error message you see, including in what line it appears.

Comment: Please **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`DataInputStream.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine--): ***Deprecated.** This method does not properly convert bytes to characters. As of JDK 1.1, the preferred way to read lines of text is via the `BufferedReader.readLine()` method.* --- JDK 1.1 was released in **1997**, so unless your code is more than 22 years old, what are you doing calling that method? Or why not use `Scanner` like everybody else?

Comment: Thanks @Andreas that helps...I was just checking how many ways are there to take input from user in which i find this one and used it.

Comment: You probably also don't need to use System.out.flush(); :)

Comment: I used that just in case the buffer does'nt add up to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using BufferedReader

BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

tempString = reader.readLine();

Comment: I used that and I am getting "error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown " wherever readLine() method was used

Comment: use try catch block :
try {
            tempString = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }